# Extracting data from different columns in a data frame based on row values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape

From each row in the data frame, df, I want to extract values in columns, as explained below and create a new data frame, output.

When Year is equal to 2003, I need values in Y_2001 and Y_2002 columns, in output data frame as Year 1 and Year 2. They are the values corresponding to two years prior to year specified in Year column. Similarly, if year equals to 2006, I need values in Y_2004 and Y_2005 in output data frame. Likewise, for all years in Year column.

```
> df
     ID Year Y_2001 Y_2002 Y_2003 Y_2004 Y_2005
[1,]  1 2003      2      4      6      4      3
[2,]  2 2004      5      9      7      1      2
[3,]  3 2006      4      3      5      7      8
[4,]  4 2004      7      6      4      8      9

> output
     ID Year Year1 Year2
[1,]  1 2003     2     4
[2,]  2 2004     9     7
[3,]  3 2006     7     8
[4,]  4 2004     6     4
```

Can someone please help me to create a code to get above output? Highly appreciate any support.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

Would take data and put into long form with `pivot_longer`. The data values of interest are where the Year "row" is 1 or 2 years less than the "column" Year. You can `filter` on these differences (`filter` here is explicit for 1 or 2 year differences).

An additional column is created with `mutate` for your column names of `Year1` and `Year2` (note `Year1` is difference of 2 years, and `Year2` is difference of 1 year, so the values is subtracted from 3 for this reversal). Finally, `pivot_wider` puts the data back in wide form.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, Year), names_to = c(".value", "Year_Sep"), names_sep = "_", names_ptypes = list(Year_Sep = numeric())) %>%
  filter(Year - Year_Sep == 1 | Year - Year_Sep == 2) %>%
  mutate(YearCol = paste0("Year", 3 - (Year - Year_Sep))) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, Year), names_from = YearCol, values_from = Y)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     ID  Year Year1 Year2
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1  2003     2     4
2     2  2004     9     7
3     3  2006     7     8
4     4  2004     6     4
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a clunky solution, but ...

```
i.col <- function(data, n) { # Returns the column index corresponding to the year
  sapply(data$Year-n, function(x) grep(x, names(data)))
}

df$Year1 <- diag(as.matrix(df[, i.col(df, n=2)]))
df$Year2 <- diag(as.matrix(df[, i.col(df, n=1)]))
```

**Edit**: 
Apparently using `diag` is very [slow](http://eamoncaddigan.net/r/programming/2015/10/22/indexing-matrices/). Using `cbind` to access matrix elements is preferred.

```
df$Year1 <- df[cbind(1:4, i.col(df, n=2))] # where 4 is number of rows
df$Year2 <- df[cbind(1:4, i.col(df, n=1))]
```

---

```
df
  ID Year Y_2001 Y_2002 Y_2003 Y_2004 Y_2005 Year1 Year2
1  1 2003      2      4      6      4      3     2     4
2  2 2004      5      9      7      1      2     9     7
3  3 2006      4      3      5      7      8     7     8
4  4 2004      7      6      4      8      9     6     4
```

Comment: I was wondering about something similar. This was helpful for me to see, thank you.

Comment: Yeah - I don't like the `diag` bit, but I couldn't figure out how to select individual elements of a matrix. >.<

Comment: Thanks a lot @Edward. For a bigger data set, lets say if I need to extract data for 50 years- is there a way to do it from one code, without writing a code for each year (df$Year49, df$Year50 etc?

Comment: Probably, using `lapply` or similar.  But I'd need to see a sample of the data and the expected output before suggesting the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with row-wise `apply` assuming that you can find out the starting year (`2001`).

```
cbind(df[1:2], t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) 
               { vals <- x[1] - 2001; x[c(vals:(vals + 1))]})))

#  ID Year 1 2
#1  1 2003 2 4
#2  2 2004 9 7
#3  3 2006 7 8
#4  4 2004 6 4
```